# get kendo scheduler data source after binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

How do I retrieve the data from a Kendo Scheduler after the data is bound to the scheduler.  I have a javascript function set up to fire after the grid data is bound.  When that javascript function fires I need to get the datasource from the grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Optic_Freedom.Areas.Scheduling.Models.CalendarViewModel>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Date(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day))
            .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 07, 00, 00))
            .EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 23, 00, 00))
            .Editable(false)
            .Height(900)
            .Events(e=> e.DataBound("someFunction"))
            .EventTemplate(
                "<div style='font-size:8pt;'>#= kendo.toString(title) # - #= kendo.toString(start, 'HH:mm') # - #= kendo.toString(end, 'HH:mm') # (#= kendo.toString(TotalPersonnel) #)</div>" 
            )
            .Views(views =>
            {
                views.DayView();
                views.MonthView(month => month.Selected(true).DayTemplate("<div id=\"DayClass\" style='float:left'><span class=\"theDate\">#= kendo.toString(date, 'dd')#</span> - (<span id=\"PersonnelDayCount\"/>)</div>"));
                views.AgendaView(a =>a.Title("Event List"));
            })
            .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m => m.Id(f => f.Id))
            .Read("GetSchedule", "ScheduleHome")
            )
      )
```

--javascript function trying to get the data

```
function someFunction(e) {
        var model = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        -- can't get the model data
}
```

What do I need to put in the someFunction(e) to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed 
  var model = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource;

then from there I can loop through the model with 
  $.each(model.data(), function (index, item) { do something...});

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are looking for:

```
var data = this.dataSource.data();
```